# Animate.css's fadeInLeft & fadeInRight at the same time

Tags: html, css, animate.css

I want to use Animate.css's fadeInLeft and fadeInRight at the same time, but when the elements appear, the horizontal scrolling becomes huger than the actual screen size.

Let me show you what I mean.

Each element is coming from the left and right side and, at the same time, the horizontal scrolling appears. When the elements are arriving to next to each other, the horizontal scrolling disappears as it should be.

[image]

The code I use:

HTML

```
<div class="tc">
    <div class="fl w-50">
        <div class="animate fadeInLeft">
        <img src="https://i.imgbox.com/Ism1Ekjf.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fl w-50">
        <div class="animate fadeInRight">
        <img src="https://i.imgbox.com/Ism1Ekjf.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tc { text-align: center; }
.fl { float: left; _display: inline; }
.w-50 { width: 50%; }
```

And Animate.css library: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/animate.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add overflow-x: hidden; to your body CSS.

This is not an ideal situation but should do the trick! This basically tells the browser to ignore anything overflowing the x-axis (horizontally). If you ever want to use the horizontal scrollbar you will need a different solution.

Comment: That's ok, please accept as answer and upvote if you're happy. :)